# Model in sub-directory via app_label?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

In order to place my models in sub-folders I tried to use the app_label Meta field as described [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label).

My directory structure looks like this:

- project

  - apps

    - foo

      - models

        - __init__.py
        - bar_model.py

In bar_model.py I define my Model like this:

```
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):

    field = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "foo"
```

I can successfully import the model like so:

```
from apps.foo.models.bar_model import SomeModel
```

However, running:

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

does not create the table for the model. In verbose mode I do see, however, that the app "foo" is properly recognized (it's in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py). Moving the model to models.py under foo does work.

Is there some specific convention not documented with app_label or with the whole mechanism that prevents this model structure from being recognized by syncdb?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See Django ticket [#10985: Explain how models can be organised in a directory](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10985)

It may be that you aren't importing your models into `__init__.py`?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, you'll need to import them into `__init__.py` and give them an `app_label` via the model's `Meta` class.

Comment: Important the addition from @mustafa.0x you *must* provide same app_label than the label name you provide as module name or the one you provide in AppConfig registry if not it would return an empty OrderedDict() if you get apps.get_app_config('app_label').models after importing django.apps.apps

Answer (score 3):

`syncdb` will not create tables for models not located in `<appname>.models`, so import it in there, e.g. `from apps.foo.models import SomeModel`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either, i.e. syncdb doesn't pick up SomeModel.

Comment: EDIT: I now realize you were pointing in the same direction as Van Gale. I've marked his as the correct answer because it also contains a link to the discussion about proper documentation of app_label.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you have a newer version of Django, supposing you have a subfolder named `subfolder` :

in `apps.py` of your folder app:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        from myapp.subfolder import models
```