# How can I let Django load models from subpackages of apps?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I essentially have the following issue:

Say, the model classes I define are in `/app/cog/models.py`, but Django only checks for them in `/app/models.py` . Is there any way to let Django **dynamically** read all the model classes in all models.py files in all subpackages of `app`?

It might be noteworthy that I really want to follow Django's philosophy concerning apps, which includes "all apps are independent from each other". So, I don't want to give those subpackages their own apps, or otherwise people who use my app would possibly end up with 50 apps after some time (as these subpackages simply extend the functionality of the app, and there will probably be a lot of them).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Along with `app`, also add `app.cog` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Or, include *app/cog/models.py* in *app/models.py* (i.e. `from .cog.models import *` or `from .cog.models import model1, model2`)

Comment: Wow, it's that easy? :|

Comment: Oops, Enter submits a commit, sorry for this double comment. Can I import things within a for? Sorry for my terrible English today.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you...import things within what?

Comment: Can I import from packages from within a for loop? Like `for cog in cogs:\n    from .cog.model import *`

Comment: `for cog in cogs:` `from .cog.models import *` – sorry. ^^'

Comment: Nevermind, the question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480060/model-in-sub-directory-via-app-label . I'll mark it as a duplicate. :)